# TSQL Case on the From clause

Tags: t-sql, view

in my LiveAppDB we have a load of views which reference a larger LiveProduction DB. What I'd like to do is switch the code to look at the TestProduction DB, depending on which Application DB the view is running on

```
-- VIEW CAN RUN ON LiveApplicationDB or TestApplicationDB
SELECT      COL1, COL2 
FROM            (CASE WHEN DB_NAME() = ‘LiveApplicationDB‘ THEN     LIVEPRODUCTION.DB.DBTABLE ELSE TESTPRODUCTION.DB.DBTABLE END) AS tabl1 -- CASE TO DETERMINE WHICH PRODUCTION DB TO USE
INNER JOIN      dbo.ThisDBTable BRA
ON          tabl1.product COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN = BRA.product
WHERE        (tabl1.COL1 IS NOT NULL)
```

In a bid to help clarify this…
If the view LiveAppDB use LiveProductionDB else TestAppDB use TestProductionDB

Obviously you can’t use variables in a View.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: did any of these answers work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Create a synonym in LiveProductionDB pointing to LIVEPRODUCTION.DB.DBTABLE and a synonym with the same exact name in TestAppDB pointing to TESTPRODUCTION.DB.DBTABLE. Use the synonym in your query. You probably should put something like this in your deployment script:

```
IF DB_NAME() = 'LiveApplicationDB'
    CREATE SYNONYM dbo.DBTABLE FOR LIVEPRODUCTION.DB.DBTABLE;
IF DB_NAME() = 'LiveApplicationDB'
    CREATE SYNONYM dbo.DBTABLE FOR TESTPRODUCTION.DB.DBTABLE;
```

FYI: Most compare tools I've tried ignore the destination of a synonym and thus this will not be considered a difference.

EDIT: I'd recommend never to use a object in an other database directly. For example: when dbA needs some objects in dbB, I'd create a schema in dbA called dbB and place synonyms in this schema referencing the objects in dbB from dbA. In most cases I'd also create a schema called dbA in dbB and place views and sprocs there only to be used by dbA. dbA is only allowed to use objects placed in the dbA schema in dbB. To futher explain the reasoning behind this approach:

- All dependancies on dbB from dbA are clearly stated in both databases
- Moving dbB to another server is a breeze, simply create a linked server and modify all synonyms. No sproc needs to be modified or tested.
- Datamodel changes dbB don't necessarily mean you'd need to make changes in dbA, just make sure the interfaces of the objects in schema dbA in dbB remain the same.
- All code that matters is exactly the same between test and production which benefits deployments and code compares

Comment: sorry, what I forgot to mention is that the TestApplicationDB will be overwritten by the LiveApplicationDB (just to add a further level of complexity). I have found this[link]https://www.ideosity.com/how-to-find-and-replace-text-in-all-stored-procedures/, which I could run following a restore over test.

Answer (score 0):

If the servers are linked, then you can use a four-part naming convention to point to your test instance - just qualify the name like so:
(CASE WHEN DB_NAME() = 'LiveApplicationDB' THEN     LiveServer.LIVEPRODUCTION.DB.DBTABLE ELSE TestServer.TESTPRODUCTION.DB.DBTABLE END
But you'll have to get your DBA to agree to link the servers, or do it yourself, if you have the knowledge/power.

Donna

Answer (score 0):

I'd approach this slightly differently to how you're doing it. You're always using the table dbo.ThisDBTable. Use this as the base table then join to the others with the `db_name()` check in the `ON` clause;

```
-- VIEW CAN RUN ON LiveApplicationDB or TestApplicationDB
SELECT BRA.COL1
    ,COLLATE(tab1.COL2, tab2.COL2) COL2
FROM dbo.ThisDBTable BRA
LEFT JOIN LIVEPRODUCTION.DB.DBTABLE tab1
    ON BRA.product = tab1.product COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN
    AND DB_NAME() = 'LiveApplicationDB'
LEFT JOIN TESTPRODUCTION.DB.DBTABLE tab2
    ON BRA.product = tab2.product COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN
    AND DB_NAME() = 'TestProductionDB'
WHERE tab1.COL1 IS NOT NULL
```